# Auto layout only returning single device width. Expecting device that is being used width

Tags: xcode, swift3, autolayout

I'm trying to set my UIImageView corner radius to produce a circular UIImageView. However, when I run my app on an iPhone 7 Plus the image isn't quiet circular.

```
    imageOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = imageOutlet.frame.size.width / 2
```

While debugging this issue, I noticed that the width returned was the same regardless of the device. Then, when I changed the "view as: iPhone 7 (w C, h R)" near the bottom of the storyboard to iPhone 7 Plus, all worked as expected on iPhone 7 Plus and did not work correctly on iPhone 7.

My constraints for the UIImageView used are as follows:
[image: UIImageView constraints]

My intention is to be able to get the width of the UIImageView as it is on the device that is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wrestling with this problem for a while I have finally found a solution.

**Summary**: Calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on my `UIImageView` outlet before calling `.frame.size.width` yields the correct width for the device that is running the application.

**Details**:
My `setAppearance()` function is called in the `viewDidLoad()` function. During `viewDidLoad()` call, the application returned a width that was based on the default device (in my case: iPhone 7). This happened even when I was running on the iPhone 7 Plus simulator. However, calling width anytime after `viewDidLoad()` yielded the correct width based on the device that was running the application.

Below, i'm running the application on an iPhone 7s Plus and printing the width during the `viewDidLoad` function. The width changes from 281.0 (iPhone 7 expected size) to 310.6667 (iPhone 7 Plus expected size) when called again, after the `viewDidLoad()` fn.

[image]

This results in unsatisfactory as my image is not completely circular (my intention with the `.frame.size.width/2` call).

However, calling `layoutIfNeeded()` fn right before accessing the `width` member of my `UIImageView` yields the following width during the `viewDidLoad()` fn.

[image]

By forcing the layout of the `UIImageView` with `layoutIfNeeded()` before accusing the width, the application receives the correct width based on the device during the `viewDidLoad` function.
visit https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Add width/height constraints on the `UIImageView` to force them to be equal. If the width/height of the image is dependent on the screen size, you will get weird results like you described. Since you have a trailing/leading constraint of 42 pixels to the Superview, the width of the image is going to be different depending on the device. The formula you used only works with equal width/height.

Comment: With width/height constraints, the `UIImageView` would be a fixed size regardless of the device. My intent is to have the `UIImageView` scale to each device. Thus, with 42 trailing/leading I have an appropriate buffer on either end and with 1:1 ratio the height is constrained.

Comment: Make sure you are setting the corner radius after the frame size is calculated. That's my only other idea.